# django formset for 3 foreign keys giving me error of [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a formset of 3 foreign keys. Servicer, Sdescrition, and Stag. For some reason it is give me this error

> ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

I am pretty new at coding, if there is a better way than inlineform_factory please let me know and suggest. Thank you very much. I am pretty much trying to connect three foreign keys together put them into a single form page on the webpage. Once again, Thank you

**Views.py**

```python
def home(request):
title = 'Please Enter Company Information'

SdescriptionFormSet = inlineformset_factory( Servicer, Sdescription, form = InputFormSdescription, extra=1)

StagFormSet = inlineformset_factory( Sdescription, Stag, form = InputFormStag, extra=1) #new
Sdescription_formset = InputFormSdescription()
Stag_formset = StagFormSet()


if request.POST:

    FormServicer = InputFormServicer(request.POST or None)

    FormSdescription = InputFormSdescription(request.POST or None) #new



    if FormServicer.is_valid() and FormSdescription.is_valid():

        servicer = FormServicer.save(commit=False)
        Sdescription_formset=SdescriptionFormSet(request.POST, instance =servicer)

        sdescription = FormSdescription.save(commit=False)   #new
        Stag_formset=StagFormSet(request.POST, instance =sdescription) #new


        if Sdescription_formset.is_valid():

            servicer.save()
            Sdescription_formset.save()
            sdescription.save() #n
            Stag_formset.save() #new
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('serv.views.home'))

else:
    FormServicer = InputFormServicer()
    Sdescription_formset = SdescriptionFormSet(instance=Servicer())
    Stag_formset=StagFormSet(instance=Sdescription())

context = {
    "title": title,
    "FormServicer": FormServicer,
    "Sdescription_formset": Sdescription_formset,
    "Stag_formset": Stag_formset,  #new

}
return render(request, 'serv.html', context)
```

**Models.py:**

```python
class Servicer(models.Model):
servicer_name = models.CharField(max_length=45,unique=True)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.servicer_name

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
was_published_recently.boolean = True
was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
# adds view site button on admin.
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/video/%s/' % self.id 

class Sdescription(models.Model):
servicer = models.ForeignKey(Servicer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

address = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
address_line_2= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
city= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
state= models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
zip = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
near_landmark = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

main_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
comments = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
website = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length = 20,blank=True, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.address, 
              self.address_line_2, self.city, self.state, self.zip, 
self.near_landmark, self.phone_number1, self.phone_number2, self.comments,
  self.website, self.email)

class Stag(models.Model):
tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True, null=True)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2,blank=True, 
null=True)
comments = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)

sdescription = models.ForeignKey(Sdescription, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return '%s $%s %s' % (self.tag_name, self.price, self.comments)
```

**Forms.py:**

```python
class InputFormServicer(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Servicer
    fields=['servicer_name']


class InputFormSdescription(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sdescription
    fields=['address','address_line_2','city','state','zip','near_landmark',
    'main_contact_name', 'phone_number1', 'phone_number2', 'comments',
    'website', 'email','image'
    ]



class InputFormStag(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Stag
    fields=['tag_name','price','comments']
```

**Serv.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{FormServicer}}

{{Sdescription_formset.as_p}}
{{Sdescription_formset.management_form}}

{{Stag_formset.as_p}}
{{Stag_formset.management_form}}
<input type='submit' value='save'/>
</form>
```